# Simple join of two Spark DataFrame failing with "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Cannot resolve column name"

Tags: csv, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**Update**
It turns out this has something to do with the way the Databricks Spark CSV reader is creating the DataFrame.  In the example below that does not work, I read the people and address CSV using Databricks CSV reader, then write the resulting DataFrame to HDFS in Parquet format.

I changed the code to create the DataFrame with: (similar for the people.csv)

```
JavaRDD<Address> address = context.textFile("/Users/sfelsheim/data/address.csv").map(
            new Function<String, Address>() {
                public Address call(String line) throws Exception {
                    String[] parts = line.split(",");

                    Address addr = new Address();
                    addr.setAddrId(parts[0]);
                    addr.setCity(parts[1]);
                    addr.setState(parts[2]);
                    addr.setZip(parts[3]);

                    return addr;
                }
            });
```

and then write the resulting DataFrame to HDFS in Parquet format, **and the join works as expected**

I am reading the exact same CSV in both cases.

---

Running into an issue trying to perform a simple join of two DataFrames created from two different parquet files on HDFS.

---

[main] INFO org.apache.spark.SparkContext - **Running Spark version 1.4.1**

Using HDFS from **Hadoop 2.7.0**

---

Here is a sample to illustrate.

```
 public void testStrangeness(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local[*]").setAppName("joinIssue");
    JavaSparkContext context = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    SQLContext sqlContext = new SQLContext(context);

    DataFrame people = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs://localhost:9000//datalake/sample/people.parquet");
    DataFrame address = sqlContext.parquetFile("hdfs://localhost:9000//datalake/sample/address.parquet");

    people.printSchema();
    address.printSchema();

    // yeah, works
    DataFrame cartJoin = address.join(people);
    cartJoin.printSchema();

    // boo, fails 
    DataFrame joined = address.join(people,
            address.col("addrid").equalTo(people.col("addressid")));

    joined.printSchema();
}
```

---

*Contents of people*

```
first,last,addressid 
your,mom,1 
fred,flintstone,2
```

*Contents of address*

```
addrid,city,state,zip
1,sometown,wi,4444
2,bedrock,il,1111
```

---

```
people.printSchema();
```

results in...

```
root
 |-- first: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addressid: integer (nullable = true)

address.printSchema();
```

results in...

```
root
 |-- addrid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- zip: integer (nullable = true)


DataFrame cartJoin = address.join(people);
cartJoin.printSchema();
```

Cartesian join works fine, printSchema() results in...

```
root
 |-- addrid: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- city: string (nullable = true)
 |-- state: string (nullable = true)
 |-- zip: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- first: string (nullable = true)
 |-- last: string (nullable = true)
 |-- addressid: integer (nullable = true)
```

This join...

```
DataFrame joined = address.join(people,
address.col("addrid").equalTo(people.col("addressid")));
```

Results in the following exception.

```
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: **Cannot resolve column name "addrid" among (addrid, city, state, zip);**
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:159)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame$$anonfun$resolve$1.apply(DataFrame.scala:159)
    at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.resolve(DataFrame.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.col(DataFrame.scala:558)
    at dw.dataflow.DataflowParser.testStrangeness(DataflowParser.java:36)
    at dw.dataflow.DataflowParser.main(DataflowParser.java:119)
```

---

I tried changing it so people and address have a common key attribute (addressid) and used..

```
address.join(people, "addressid");
```

But got the same result.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the problem was the CSV file was in UTF-8 format with a BOM.  The DataBricks CSV implementation does not handle UTF-8 with BOM.  Converted the files to UTF-8 *without* the BOM and all works fine.

Comment: Can you explain what BOM is in this context?

Comment: BOM is Byte Order Mark   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2223882/whats-different-between-utf-8-and-utf-8-without-bom

Answer (score 0):

Was able to fix this by using Notepad++.  Under the "Encoding" menu, I switched it from "Encode in UTF-8 BOM" to "Encode in UTF-8".